# How to build multiple solutions as a list using MSBuild build step in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

We are moving from TFS 2015 to TFS 2017 and I want to build multiple Solutions of my choice as a list and not all.I am using MSBuild build step for this,therefore how can I customise  my MSBuild build step to do so.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT: Yes I did check your reply but accordingly to our requirement wildcard is not a good option and then also adding multiple MSBuild tasks is not feasible when we would want to build large number of solutions.

Comment: How about cloak the solutions that you don't want to build in workspace mapping?

Answer (score 0):

"Project" field in MSBuild task doesn't support a list a solutions separated by ';'.This field only supports Wildcards.

If the solutions you want to build can be filtered by Wildcards, then you can define them with Wildcards. Otherwise, you need to add multiple MSBuild tasks and specify the solution you want to build one by one.